# SML: How can I simulate a counter in SML without having an additional argument

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml

I have a recursive function in SML that does a certain computation that doesn't really matter for my question. What I want to do is I want to track the number of times the recursion has taken place, as in I want to count the iterations of my algorithm. I know if for example I declared:

```
val counter = 0;
val counter = counter + 1;
```

The other counter is a different variable. It is not the same one incremented by one. So this type of incrementing will lose its scope in one recursive call.

Is there any way I can keep track?

Comment: If you must, you _can_ do imperative programming in SML to achieve that (and I'm sure you'll get a few answers along these lines). But usually that's a mistake, and leads to more brittle and, in cases like this, even to slower code. The question to ask is why do you _want_ to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`int ref`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Standard_ML_Programming/Types#References) as a mutable cell:

```
val counter : int ref = ref 0

-- Some dummy recursive function for testing
fun factorial n =
  if n < 1
  then 1
  else (counter := !counter + 1; n * factorial (n - 1))
```

You can use it like this:

```
- !counter;
val it = 0 : int
- factorial 10;
val it = 3628800 : int
- !counter;
val it = 10 : int
- factorial 5;
val it = 120 : int
- !counter;
val it = 15 : int
```